# how to genrate a table in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am creating a table in angular, How can I generate new row in table with different data, for example I was doing this code in pure Js. I am able to generate a new row on calling of addRow() method. I am new to angular and I realise this is not angular way.can you please help How can I achieve the same in angular. everything is fine but I stuck because I realise I can not create a button in row `row.insertCell(5).innerHTML= '<button (click)="deleteFunc()">click</button>';` this was not working.

```js
addRow(){
     let table = document.getElementById("tableData");
     let rowcount = table.rows.length;
     let row = table.insertRow(rowcount);
     
     row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= rowcount;
     row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= this.qty;
     row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= this.log;
     row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= this.kw;
     row.insertCell(4).innerHTML= this.frame;
     row.insertCell(5).innerHTML= '<button (click)="deleteFunc()">click</button>';
     }
```

```html
<table id="tableData" border="1" >
  <tr>
    <th>S.No.</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Type Refrence</th>
    <th>KW Rating</th>
    <th>Frame Size</th>
    <th>Operation</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Look for `ngfor` in https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax. Pleae check the basic tutorials before asking questions.

Comment: what language is it written.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better ! You **need to learn Angular** before asking questions. This is a helping forum, not a learning one !

Comment: I checked the ngfor but i am not iterating an array.  in my case value of `this.qty` and 'this.log` is different for each row.

Comment: @trichetriche If you are not able to say it any better, why post a duplicate comment in a less polite way then Gunter instead of only voting on his comment?

Comment: Because I can. Why did you answer to me saying that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is so much easier in Angular. You only have to store your data in an array. Then you can iterate over it via `*ngFor`.

TS:

```
rows: any = [{
    number: 0,
    qty: 'somevalue',
    log: 'somevalue',
    kw: 'somevalue',
    frame: 'somevalue'
},{
    number: 1,
    qty: 'somevalue2',
    log: 'somevalue2',
    kw: 'somevalue2',
    frame: 'somevalue2'
}];
```

Template:

```
<table id="tableData" border="1" >
  <tr>
    <th>S.No.</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Type Refrence</th>
    <th>KW Rating</th>
    <th>Frame Size</th>
    <th>Operation</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <td>{{row.number}}</td>
    <td>{{row.qty}}</td>
    <td>{{row.log}}</td>
    <td>{{row.kw}}</td>
    <td>{{row.frame}}</td>
    <td><button (click)="deleteFunc()">click</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using javascript to handle tables which is not necessary.

To use Grids to display data in Angular, You can use third party grid controls which are very effective and easy to use.

Check these:

NgPrime

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable